# Purpose of this coding style

Tags: microcontroller, c, lpc

I came across this piece of code for an LPCxxxx microcontroller, in the reset routine.

```
do {
    const uint32_t topOfStack = (uint32_t) &_vStackTop;
    __set_PSP(topOfStack);
    __set_MSP(topOfStack);
} while(0);
```

I was wondering why this is inside a do-while loop (which executes only once) instead of writing those instructions in a straight-forward way (by which I mean outside the loop)

Comment: There is an answer of this practice over at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, not covered in the [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/), it gives you the opportunity to declare a local variable that is shared among the three statements and used nowhere else.

This kind of explicit optimization of storage can be important on small microcontrollers.

Comment: The curly braces alone would do that, without the `do` and the `while(0);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: were these available in early C dialects too?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I haven't looked, but as far as I know C has always been block scoped.

Comment: Prior to the wonders of ANSI C, whether the block scope would achieve this was implementation dependent. I seem to recall that the very early Lattice C would not - it promoted the variable to function scope.

Comment: Note that I countered the downvote because this method is *guaranteed* to achieve the requirement (as stated by Dave Tweed) even when the compiler may not be ANSI compliant (the state of play for many years).

Comment: Good luck finding a pre-ANSI compiler that supports `uint32_t`. I'm quite confident that the do-while(0) is superfluous and`{}` is sufficient, on every known compiler in the world. Though of course if your compiler isn't a piece of ancient junk, you don't need the braces at all. Skip them and thereby encourage/enforce people to use compilers that aren't older than 17 years (made after the year 1999).